# Extract multiple tokens from json path using Regex

Tags: java, regex, token

I have to extract tokens from a text which I need to match using regex. An example text would be something like this.

```
data.orderType.`order.created.time`
```

Right now I'm using the following regex to tokenize this string.

```
`(.*?)`|[^.]+
```

This regex tokenizes the string partially, and gives tokens as

```
data,orderType,`order.created.time`
```

the problem here is when the tokens are taken backtick also gets included. How can I dump the backtick and just get the following?

```
data,orderType,order.created.time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already captured the part between backticks, just grab `matcher.group(1)` if it participated in the match (=if it matched):

[Java demo](https://rextester.com/VAI35348):

```
String s = "data.orderType.`order.created.time`";
String regex = "`([^`]*)`|[^.`]+";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
   if (m.group(1) != null) {
       result.add(m.group(1));
   } else {
       result.add(m.group());
   }
}
System.out.println(result);
// => [data, orderType, order.created.time]
```

Note I also added a backtick to the negated character class, `` [^.`]+ `` as I assume the backticks can only be paired.